# Multiple values of tuples

Tags: python, numpy, tuples, approximation

I have problem with approximation in python.
I have a function, which gives me a dict with results. For example `{1: 0.5, 2: 0.25}`. It means that `f(1)==0.5`, `f(2)==0.25`, etc.

Below is what I do after getting values from my function.

```
lists = sorted(resultsDict.items())
x, y = zip(*lists)
startvalues = [0.5,1.0,0]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y,p0)
function=func(x,popt[0],popt[1],popt[2])
plt.plot(x,y,'x',x,function,'r-')
plt.show()
```

And now I have answer. If I define function func in that way everything is OK.

```
def func(x,a,b,c):
   return  a+b/x
```

If I define that way

```
def func(x,a,b,c):
   return  a+b/x+c*x
```

I have error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

And if I define that way

```
def func(x,a,b,c):
   return  a+b/x+c/(x*x) # or x**2
```

I have error:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple'
```

I don't know, where is a problem especially in second one and I don't know how can I dodge problem in third one if I wanted to check function `1/x**2`.

Comment: So `x` and `y` are lists and not numpy arrays? Is `curve_fit` coming from numpy? give us an example of `x` and `y`.

Comment: instead of the first two lines, try `x,y=np.array(sorted(resultsDict.items())).T`, probably your problem is that you are trying to do math with tuples in `x` and `y`, but simply need numpy arrays in them.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize, that numpy has a nice data structure ;)

Comment: so that was your problem? I'll submit it as an answer then

Answer (score 0):

The first two lines of your code render `x` and `y` as tuples which act different than numpy arrays to mathematical operators. All you need to do is:
`x,y=np.array(sorted(resultsDict.items())).T`
This makes a numpy array for you, then transpose it so it has 2 rows and n columns, so it can be unpacked onto `x,y`.